# Wrapper routine for write() with unistd.h included results in error

Tags: c, linux, wrapper

I am writing a wrapper routine for `write()` to override the original system function and within it i need to execute another program through `execve()`; for which I include the header file `unistd.h`. I get the error **`conflicting types for 'write' /usr/include/unistd.h:363:16: note: previous declaration of 'write'was here`**. I would be very gratefull if someone could help me out as I need to call another program from inside the wrapper and also send arguments to it from inside the wrapper routine.

Comment: If you are writing a wrapper routine you should not use the same name as the one you are trying to wrap. Or use names that might exist in the header. Look at your error better. it says what is the problem. You should also show some code.

Comment: If I don't use the same name as the one I am trying to wrap then how will my function get called instaed of the original write system call.

Comment: Look at "[weak symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)".  That said, this is a *very* dangerous thing to do; make sure it's really the only way to do what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using the GNU liner `--wrap symbol` option as [suggested by Matthew Slattery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182056/a-wrapper-routine-for-write-with-include-unistd-h-in-the-function-gives-error/5206744#5206744) would be to use [`dlsym()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) to obtain the address of the `execve()` symbol at runtime in order to avoid the compile-time issues with including `unistd.h`.

I suggest reading [Jay Conrod's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891/jay-conrod) blog post entitled [*Tutorial: Function Interposition in Linux*](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23) for additional information on replacing calls to functions in dynamic libraries with calls to your own wrapper functions.

The following example provides a `write()` wrapper function that calls the original `write()` before calling `execve()` and does not include `unistd.h`.  It is important to note that you cannot directly call the original `write()` from the wrapper because it will be interpreted as a recursive call to the wrapper itself.

***Code:***

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

size_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    static size_t (*write_func)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;    
    static int (*execve_func)(const char *, char *const[], char *const[]) = NULL;

    /* arguments for execve()  */
    char *path = "/bin/echo";
    char *argv[] = { path, "hello world", NULL };
    char *envp[] = { NULL };

    if (!write_func)
    {
        /* get reference to original (libc provided) write */
        write_func = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");
    }

    if (!execve_func)
    {
        /* get reference to execve */
        execve_func = (int(*)(const char *, char *const[], char *const[])) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "execve");
    }

    /* call original write() */
    write_func(fd, buf, count);

    /* call execve() */
    return execve_func(path, argv, envp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int filedes = 1;
    char buf[] = "write() called\n";
    size_t nbyte = sizeof buf / sizeof buf[0];

    write(filedes, buf, nbyte);

    return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

> $ gcc -Wall -Werror -ldl test.c -o test
>   $ ./test
>   write() called
>   hello world
>   $

<sub>**Note: This code is provided as an example of what is possible.  I would recommend following [Jonathan Leffler's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182056/a-wrapper-routine-for-write-with-include-unistd-h-in-the-function-gives-error/5183403#5183403) on code segregation in constructing the final implementation.**</sub>

Comment: The trouble starts when you want to mock dlopen and dlsym itself, ouch...

Answer (score 5):

The GNU linker has a `--wrap <symbol>` option which allows you to do this sort of thing.

If you link with `--wrap write`, references to `write` will redirect to `__wrap_write` (which you implement), and references to `__real_write` will redirect to the original `write` (so you can call it from within your wrapper implementation).

Here's a sophisticated test application using `write()` - I'm doing the compilation and linking steps separately because I'll want to use `hello.o` again in a minute:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    write(0, "Hello, world!\n", 14);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -Wall -c hello.c
$ gcc -o test1 hello.o
$ ./test1
Hello, world!
$
```

Here's an implementation of `__wrap_write()`, which calls `__real_write()`.  (Note that we want a prototype for `__real_write` to match the original.  I've added a matching prototype explicitly, but another possible option is to `#define write __real_write` *before* `#include <unistd.h>`.)

```
$ cat wrapper.c
#include <unistd.h>

extern ssize_t __real_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t n);

ssize_t __wrap_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t n)
{
    __real_write(fd, "[wrapped] ", 10);
    return __real_write(fd, buf, n);
}
$ gcc -Wall -c wrapper.c
$
```

Now, link the `hello.o` we made earlier with `wrapper.o`, passing the appropriate flags to the linker.  (We can pass arbitrary options through `gcc` to the linker using the slightly odd `-Wl,option` syntax.)

```
$ gcc -o test2 -Wl,--wrap -Wl,write hello.o wrapper.o
$ ./test2
[wrapped] Hello, world!
$
```

Comment: This solution works for me . Its just the the dlsym() solution suggested later seems more feasible for my project. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It is an utterly bad idea to try wrapping `write()` and use POSIX functions.  If you chose to work in standard C, then you could wrap `write()` because it is not a name reserved to the standard.  However, once you start using POSIX functions - and `execve()` is a POSIX function - then you are running into conflicts; POSIX reserves the name `write()`.

If you want to try, you may get away with it if you segregate the code carefully.  You have your `write()` wrapper in one source file which does not include `<unistd.h>` or use any functions not defined in the C standard for the headers you do include.  You have your code that does the `execve()` in a second file that does include `<unistd.h>`.  And you link those parts together with appropriate function calls.

If you are lucky, it will work as intended.  If you aren't lucky, all hell will break loose.  And note that your luck status might change on different machines depending on factors outside your control such as o/s updates (bug fixes) or upgrades.  It is a very fragile design decision to wrap `write()`.

Comment: @ Leffler..no it does not work as linking too would link <unistd.h> with the wrapper source file.

Comment: @Lipika: as I noted, it is at best a fragile solution. The code linked before the wrapper function might well call the `write()` wrapper function. The code in the main C library is more likely to end up using the `write()` it contains. You get the same problem trying to use your own `malloc()` (et al) function; the main libraries don't use your version, not any more. Once upon a decade or two ago, you could do it; you might still do it with statically linked libraries, but it is not guaranteed.  Life is tough.  (And note that `<unistd.h>` is not linked; the library it describes is.)

Answer (score 1):

Just making an illustration for Muggen's attention call (therefore community wiki):

You want to redefine `write` and call `write` from inside your redefinition. Something like

```
void write(int a) {
    /* code code code */
    write(42);                  /* ??? what `write`?
                                   ??? recursive `write`?
                                   ??? the other `write`? */
    /* code code code */
}
```

Better think better about it :)

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If you segregate your code appropriately as suggested by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182056/wrapper-routine-for-write-with-unistd-h-included-results-in-error/5183403#5183403), you should be able to avoid compile-time issues related to including `unistd.h`.  The following code is provided as an example of such segregation.

Note that you cannot interpose internal library function calls, since these are resolved before runtime. For instance, if some function in libc calls `write()`, it will never call your wrapper function.

***Code:***
*exec.c*

```
#include <unistd.h>

inline int execve_func(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[])
{
    return execve(path, argv, envp);
}
```

*test.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int execve_func(const char *, char *const[], char *const[]);

size_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{    
    /* arguments for execve()  */
    char *path = "/bin/echo";
    char *argv[] = { path, "hello world", NULL };
    char *envp[] = { NULL };

    return execve_func(path, argv, envp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int filedes = 1;
    char buf[] = "dummy";
    size_t nbyte = sizeof buf / sizeof buf[0];

    write(filedes, buf, nbyte);

    return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

> $ gcc -Wall -Werror test.c exec.c -o test
>   $ ./test
>   hello world
>   $

Comment: @jschmier I am sorry but I may be missing something here. I am getting an error as error:nested function 'execve_func' declared but not defined. And if I include the file exec.c in test. c as #include "exec.c" then I get the same error as before.

Comment: @Lipika - You don't need to include *exec.c* in *test.c* as `#include "exec.c"`.  In my example, the two source files are kept separate, only contain the content shown, and are combined to form the final executable via the **gcc -Wall -Werror test.c exec.c -o test** command shown in the ***Output***.

Comment: @jschmier It is while forming the final executable via gcc -Wall -Werror test.c exec.c -o test that I get the error as error:nested function 'execve_func' declared but not defined.

Comment: @jschmier I copied your example as-it-is. Thank You so much for your help and interest.

Comment: @Lipika - Happy to help.  Perhaps you will have better luck with the edit I applied to *test.c*.

Comment: @jschmier I am still getting error : cc1:warnings being treated as errors test.c: In function write: test.c:10:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'execve'. I think linking is not happening due to some reason.

Comment: @jschmier Am very sorry. Mistakes all mine. This code works perfectly. I was calling execve() instead of execve_func() from write(). But, may i ask why do you prefer this method over the dlsym() method? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Lipika - If the goal is *only* to get around issues related to including `unistd.h` in the same file as your `write()` wrapper, the code segregation approach addresses the issues at compile-time rather than run-time.  However, I do like the use of function interposition (`LD_PRELOAD` & `dlsym()`) as it can be a very powerful technique for monitoring programs or modifying their behavior.