# Preloading my library for a few functions while using the original by others using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, wrapper

I have written a wrapper for the `open()` syscall and preload it using the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. I want only a few functions of the program to use the modified `open()` whereas others would use the original. Separating the functions in two programs is not an option as one calls the other. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

The use of function interposition in the following example is similar to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182056/wrapper-routine-for-write-with-unistd-h-included-results-in-error/5212871#5212871).

The example provides a `write()` wrapper function that calls the original `write()`.  It is important to note that you cannot directly call the original `write()` because it will be interpreted as a call to the wrapper.  The use of function pointers in `main()` demonstrates how you might go about avoiding confusion as to which `write()` you are calling.

***Code:*** test.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

size_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    static size_t (*write_func)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;

    /* get reference to original (libc provided) write */
    if (!write_func)
    {
        write_func = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");
    }

    /* perform wrapper specific actions */
    /* ... */

    /* call original write() */
    return  write_func(fd, buf, count);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t (*wrap_write)(int, const void *, size_t);
    size_t (*orig_write)(int, const void *, size_t);
    char buf1[] = "write() wrapper called\n";
    char buf2[] = "orignial write() called\n";

    /* set pointer to write() wrapper to differentiate */
    wrap_write = write;
    /* get reference to original (libc provided) write() */
    orig_write = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");

    /* call write() wrapper */
    wrap_write(1, buf1, strlen(buf1));    
    /* call original write() */
    orig_write(1, buf2, strlen(buf2));

    return 0;
}
```

***Output:***

> $ gcc -Wall -Werror -ldl test.c -o test
>   $ ./test
>   write() wrapper called
>   orignial write() called
>   $

Answer (score 0):

First there must be a established way to distiguish the to-be-preloaded open from the default open. This can be done using a helper library (must be loaded dynamically), that offers another wrapped version of that special open. Replacing that one happens by preloading a variant of this library.

Comment: Am not sure I understand your solution. Can you be more clear. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Use a different function name for your wrappered open.

Comment: @lipika: Just think about it: By which criterion shall be decided if your wrapping "open" is to be used, or the one from the system. Once you figured out this, the rest should be clear.