# Autograding: Catching all output from code in linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to autograde some work submitted by others. Say an executable is called `foo`. It is supposed to write to standard out but in some cases, annoyingly, it instead opens a file and writes to that instead.

Is there some way (in linux) of running `foo` so that all its output, no matter if written to a file or to standard out, is piped to standard out?

I do have the source code for the submissions as well which are in Java.

(Any suggested tags most welcome. I wasn't sure what to choose.)

**Added notes**

- I can't just give 0 to everyone who writes to the wrong place.  I can of course give them a bad grade but that doesn't help me.
- I don't know where they have written to. Some seem to write to files in subdirectories.

Comment: "I don't know where they have written to"... Why not? You say you have the source code? And otherwise - _why not make the task more clear or simply ask them_? I mean what sense is there in you trying to _guess_ what some pupil might have tried?

Comment: @arkascha This is autograding. The task tells them to output to standard out but some have ignored it.  I can't just give those people zero as the answers might still be right.  I could look at each piece of code individually by eye but that would take me weeks.

Comment: So you want to apply "autograding" to save time but you also want to grade in an intelligent way that evaluates answers that did not obey the rules? Sorry....

Comment: Yes! Exactly (and no problem of course.)

Comment: Well... good luck with that.

Comment: You've removed your question on SU; just wanted to say, you might want to look into **strace** (and **ltrace**) if you want to learn how to do this with a binary. It can show you all the file descriptors read and written to; so you can capture the log, then grep for the files it opens to write to. But yeah; if you've got access to the source code, it gets a lot easier as you can just hook/replace something. Adding the tag Java to avoid answers for other programming languages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5228735/874188) shows how to wrap the `write()` system call with code of your own. You could do the same for `open()` (and `fopen()` and a few more) to trap writes to files. (Do click through to the earlier question it references, which has a good discussion as well as pointers to more information about this technique.) I suppose something similar is possible on Windows, although their terminology is bound to be slightly different. (The U*x `libc` buzzword is `LD_PRELOAD`.)

Similarly, if your submissions are in source form, you could hack your compiler to wrap or replace the corresponding Java primitives. If your students are entry-level, there are probably just a few common functions you need to identify and replace. But then, maybe you could just `grep` for them in the submissions, and be done. (On the other hand, beginners are more likely to stumble over a web page which somehow convinces them that they need to write their own operating system in order to write to standard output...)